# In AWS EKS, what security group allows access to master node from kubernetes client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

When I create a EKS cluster, I can access the master node from anywhere.
Even though, the control plane security group only allows the worker to control plane connectivity (default configuration).

How can the access to the control plane be limited to a security group?

Comment: Can you show me how you configured that SG?

Comment: @ItaiGanot I only followed the 'getting started' example in AWS. I could not find an explanation in further documentation on a fleeting glance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You can't

The EKS master nodes are managed by AWS and are run in a different account. You need access to the internet in order to reach the endpoint, and security groups won't stop anyone else from hitting the public endpoint.

Run a Dig against the API server endpoint and you can see this:

```
{hash}.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com. 59 IN   A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
{hash}.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com. 59 IN   A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This is just the API endpoint though, and I suspect that the master nodes are not actually publicly accessible, only the API endpoint, and I am certain that the API has the same AWS authentication measures as any other service's public API endpoint. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#eks_region

I would suggest going through the [EKS VPC  tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html)  and the read the section in the [docs on EKS Networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-networking.html).

Comment: damn, spooky.  It's not clear at all in the documentation that this is the case, though through our experience it is in fact the case.

Comment: I think this is a new feature but it is now possible to configure EKS to use a private API endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html